# In Custom action bar if we hide any icon that space need to used by other icons or text view in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app I am using custom action bar. In that action bar I have 4 icons and 1 `textview`. For action bar I am using linear layout.

I have 4 activities in my app, each activity will have different action bar. If I open 1st activity one icon will set visibility gone. Every one of these activities will have different icons.

Question: My requirement is when icon is disable that space need to used by `textview`. I try everything but always space will end of the action bar I don't want that space.

Here is my code.

**MainActivity.class:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4;
    TextView title;
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        /*Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
*/
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

        Image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cst_ok);
        Image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cst_del);
        Image3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cst_edt);
        Image4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cst_srh);
        title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cst_txt);

        Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showdailog();
            }
        });

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,first_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,second_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent3=new Intent(MainActivity.this,third_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        });
 private void showdailog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

//                et1.setText(edt.getText());
                title.setText(edt.getText());

            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //pass
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

**FirstActivity.class:-**

```
public class first_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4;
    TextView title;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

        Image1=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_ok);
        Image2=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_del);
        Image3=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_edt);
        Image4=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_srh);
        title=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_txt);

        Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showdailog();
            }
        });

        Image3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void showdailog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

//                et1.setText(edt.getText());
                title.setText(edt.getText());

            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //pass
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.class:-**

```
public class second_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4;
    TextView title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment3);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

        Image1=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_ok);
        Image2=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_del);
        Image3=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_edt);
        Image4=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_srh);
        title=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_txt);

        Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showdailog();
            }
        });

        Image4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void showdailog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

//                et1.setText(edt.getText());
                title.setText(edt.getText());

            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //pass
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

**ThirdActivity.class:-**

```
public class third_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4;
    TextView title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment2);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

        Image1=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_ok);
        Image2=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_del);
        Image3=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_edt);
        Image4=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_srh);
        title=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cst_txt);

        Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showdailog();
            }
        });

        Image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void showdailog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

//                et1.setText(edt.getText());
                title.setText(edt.getText());

            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //pass
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

**Custom_Actionbar_layout:-**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:weightSum="5">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ok"
    android:id="@+id/cst_ok"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Custom ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/cst_txt"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/delete1"
        android:id="@+id/cst_del"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/edit"
        android:id="@+id/cst_edt"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/search"
        android:id="@+id/cst_srh"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> And my theme is  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
>
> And text view is dynamically changed text it is given by user. If any one need more details I will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the value of the `android:weightSum` attribute of your `LinearLayout` to `5`.

When you're removing a `View` from that layout (setting its visibility to `View.GONE`), the `weightSum` of your `LinearLayout` is still `5`, but the actual sum of your `View`s is only `4`, hence the empty space.

Removing the `android:weightSum` attribute from your `LinearLayout` should solve the problem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ok"
    android:id="@+id/cst_ok"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Custom ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/cst_txt"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/delete1"
        android:id="@+id/cst_del"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/edit"
        android:id="@+id/cst_edt"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/search"
        android:id="@+id/cst_srh"/>
</LinearLayout>
```